# angular directive not getting bound to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why is my angular directive not getting bound to view?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    app.directive('projectSearchModal', projectSearchModal);

    projectSearchModal.$inject = ['$modal', '$scope', 'ProjectService'];

    function projectSearchModal($modal, $scope, ProjectService) {
        // Usage:
        //     <projectSearch></projectSearch>
        // Creates:
        // 
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                project: '=',
                finishCallback: '=',
                comment: '='
            }
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {}
})()
```

Here is how I call it:

```
<button project-search-modal="" project="project" finish-callback="wipeProjectInfoFromComment" comment="currentstakeholdercomment"
                                                     class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search Projects</button>
```

The directive is definitely making it into the browser but is not getting executed (i.e. I put a breakpoint on the link definition and it never got hit)

Comment: I think the issue is 'project-search-modal=""', just have it be 'project-search-modal'

Comment: @shieldstroy no that is not the issue, doesn't work the other way either

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your directive (other then missing `}`, I guess it's copy-paste typo) is that you are trying to inject nonexistent service `$scope` into directive. It doesn't make sense, because `$scope` is not sharable service you can inject directive/other service since it tied to specific HTMLElements. So Angular throws error.

You don't need `$scope` because you already have one available in link function.

Correct directive definition:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    app.directive('projectSearchModal', projectSearchModal);

    function projectSearchModal($modal, ProjectService) {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                project: '=',
                finishCallback: '=',
                comment: '='
            }
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('link');
        }
    }

    projectSearchModal.$inject = ['$modal', 'ProjectService'];
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason that I was injecting scope is because I wanted to use the $scope functions ($on, $emit, $broadcast etc.). I assumed that these functions would not be available on my scope since I declared it as an object with only three properties. I always assumed that $scope was a service that provided the correct scope. Why is it that I can inject $scope into controllers?

Comment: This did not help. In fact, my issue is not that angular was throwing errors. My issue is that angular is doing nothing at all, neither throwing errors nor executing the directive...

Comment: If it doesn't execute directive then it might be that you didn't configure HTML right. Can you share HTML source?

Comment: figured this out. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out that I hadn't added a module (that contained the directive) to the correct MVC layout page (there are a bunch of them floating around this project).